# How can I reformat Source Code for files without file extension in WebStorm 2016.1.3?

Tags: json, ide, sublimetext2, webstorm, reformat

How can I reformat Source Code for files without file extension in WebStorm 2016.1.3 ?

Example: I've a `automated_generated_json_file_without_extension` in one line and the name of the files are always different. I don't want to configure all these file names in "File Types" Dialog and register new patterns.

In Sublime you can change the file type at the right bottom corner, is there a similar function in WebStorm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot change file type of the file on the fly in WebStorm.

Possible workarounds:

1. Have a set of files (e.g. `test.json`, `test.js` etc) somewhere in a project where you can copy-paste this file content, reformat it there and copy it back.
2. Use ["Scratch files" functionality](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/scratches.html?search=scratch) (`Tools | New Scratch File...`) and then the same copy-paste content to reformat.